# How to set new options on timeline Vis.js when zooming in and out the timeline?

Tags: javascript, vis.js

I wanted to know if there was a possiblity to set new options on the timeline when zooming in and out the timeline ?

In fact, i have elements that are stacked when i'm in month view, but when i'm in year view, i want them not to be stacked (set options stack: false on the timeline).

Is it somehow possible to know in which view we are and to set new options ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Timeline.setOptions(options)` to set new options. You can get the current visible window using `Timeline.getWindow()` to figure out how far the user has zoomed. Just check out the docs: http://visjs.org/docs/timeline/

Comment: Thanks, seems enough for my purpose